# How to call a function from razorview to cshtml.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm new to razor views and I need to pass data from a form to razor view where you can put a number and take it from your cs in a method, then I also need to be able to do the opposite, take data from the cs (a number) and pass them to the razor view.
My code actually contains this in the razor view:

```html
@page
@model CountdownWebAPP.Models.CountdownModel
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="RemainingTime" class="col-form-label">
                    Enter the number of seconds you want to count down
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="RemainingTime" name="Remainingtime" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark">Start</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Number of seconds missing:
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="col-form-label-lg">
                    
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and this in the cs code:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace CountdownWebAPP.Views
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private int time;
        [BindProperty]
        public int RemainingTimeP { get; set; }
        public void OnGet(int RemainingTime)
        {
            RemainingTimeP = RemainingTime;
        }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public void OnPost()
        {
            var RemainingTime = Request.Form["RemainingTime"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally you use/address a property from your model in your view using the `@`symbol. For example if your `CountdownWebAPP.Models.CountdownModel`contains a `RemainingTime` property, you can use it like this: `<input type="number" id="RemainingTime" name="Remainingtime" value="@RemainingTime" />`. [Razor syntax reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Do you mean from Controller to View and from View to Controller or something else ?

Comment: Yes i need to pass from controller to view and from view to controller a number (different for each case)

Comment: I can get the propery in  the cshtml with value="@RemainingTime"  it doesn't exist in the context but in the cshtml.cs is declared what i can do for solve this

Comment: In asp.net core razor pages,just use asp-for could meet your requirement.And just for confirmation,why is the model(`CountdownModel`) in view different from your .cs file(`IndexModel`)?Did they own to different page?

Comment: The model I was aiming for was a mistake, but even so from the form the onpost method is never called

Comment: What?You even can't call OnPost method?A bit amazing and it works well in my project.Could you please edit your question and provide the correct code which could reproduce the issue?